# How to rotate image clockwise?

Tags: embedded-linux, gstreamer

According to [this](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videoflip.html) the gstreamer pipeline

> gst-launch videotestsrc ! videoflip method=clockwise !
>   ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink

rotates a video stream clockwise. 
I have tested this video pipeline in the past on an embedded-Linux Leopardboard successfully but I need to rotate individual images so I modified the pipeline like this:

> gst-launch filesrc location=test.jpeg ! videoflip method=clockwise !
>   ffmpegcolorspace ! filesink location=testClockwise.jpeg

My modified pipeline causes the following errors:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoFlip:videoflip0: 
   not negotiated
Additional debug info:
../../../../src/libs/gst/base/gstbasetransform.c(2253): 
   gst_base_transform_handle_buffer (): 
   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoFlip:videoflip0:
not negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

Why is GstVideoFlip:videoflip0 not negotiated?
Why doesn't the pipeline want to preroll?
How do I fix these errors?

Edit: So. I add jpegdec and jpegenc to my pipeline like this:

> gst-launch filesrc location=test.jpeg ! jpegdec ! videoflip
>   method=clockwise ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! filesink
>   location=testClockwise.jpeg

but now get this error:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "jpegdec"

But why, since jpegdec and jpegenc are both in [gst-plugins-good Elements](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/ch01.html)?

Comment: Do a gst-inspect jpegdec. If you don't have it, it means you do not have the installed dependencies. libjpeg? Install the dependency and rebuild the gst-plugins-good or reinstall it after installing the libjpeg. There is also ffdec_jpeg or something of that sort available. Do a gst-inspect without paramaters to list of all your plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline reads a jpeg. Not a YUV/RGB. So you need to decode your jpeg file, flip it the way you are doing, reencode it to jpeg and then write it to a file.